# How to order the numbers present in a file in ascending order in python

Tags: python

For example if this is the file...

```
Batman, Bruce Wayne, high tech weapons, 70

Spiderman, Peter Parker, wrist web-shooter, 70

Superman, Clark Kent, superhuman strength, 99

Captain America, Steve Rogers, vibranium-steel shield, 71

Wonder Woman, Princess Diana, indestructible bracelets, 80

Iron Man, Tony Stark, powered armor suit, 85

Donald Knuth, Donald Knuth, computer science and mathematics, 100

Hulk, Robert Banner, superhuman strength, 90

He-Man, Prince Adam, superhuman strength, 92

Wolverine, Logan, retractable bone claws, 70
```

I am asked print the lines based on the powers(the numbers in the end of each line) of the superheroes in ascending order...

Help me out guyzz!!!

Comment: This is a really simple problem, what did you try? -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly straightforward problem, but one with a few steps. Searching for questions like "how to load a .txt file into python?" would lead you to using the pandas module, and "how to sort a pandas DataFrame by a column?" would lead you to using the sort_values DataFrame method. If you are having trouble finding answers to a question on your own, you should break it down into smaller pieces. The answers for how to do these steps are already provided in other answers on stack overflow.

To still be helpful though, here's the approach you would use. 
I'm assuming this data is stored as a .txt or .csv file.

Use pandas to read the data into a dataframe, then sort by the Power column descending. You can the output the dataframe out as a .csv, excel, .txt, or whatever filetype you want. There's plenty of answers out there on stack overflow for that step depending on what filetype you want.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sort_input.txt', delimiter=',', header=None,
                  names=['Alias','Name','Skill','Power'])
df.sort_values(['Power'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Gives the output:

```
Donald Knuth, Donald Knuth, computer science and mathematics,100
Superman, Clark Kent, superhuman strength,99
He-Man, Prince Adam, superhuman strength,92
Hulk, Robert Banner, superhuman strength,90
Wonder Woman, Princess Diana, indestructible bracelets,80
Captain America, Steve Rogers, vibranium-steel shield,71
tman, Bruce Wayne, high tech weapons,70
Spiderman, Peter Parker, wrist web-shooter,70
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = """Batman, Bruce Wayne, high tech weapons, 70
Spiderman, Peter Parker, wrist web-shooter, 70
Superman, Clark Kent, superhuman strength, 99
Captain America, Steve Rogers, vibranium-steel shield, 71
Wonder Woman, Princess Diana, indestructible bracelets, 80
Iron Man, Tony Stark, powered armor suit, 85
Donald Knuth, Donald Knuth, computer science and mathematics, 100
Hulk, Robert Banner, superhuman strength, 90
He-Man, Prince Adam, superhuman strength, 92
Wolverine, Logan, retractable bone claws, 70"""
ss = s
s = s.split('\n')
x = [e.split(',') for e in s]
x = sorted(x, key=lambda x:int(x[-1].strip()))
s = '\n'.join([','.join(e) for e in x])
```

Here you go

Comment: But dude the whole stuff is written in a file how do you store it in 's' ??

Answer (score 0):

Posting a pandas answer too:

```
s = u"""Batman, Bruce Wayne, high tech weapons, 70
Spiderman, Peter Parker, wrist web-shooter, 70
Superman, Clark Kent, superhuman strength, 99
Captain America, Steve Rogers, vibranium-steel shield, 71
Wonder Woman, Princess Diana, indestructible bracelets, 80
Iron Man, Tony Stark, powered armor suit, 85
Donald Knuth, Donald Knuth, computer science and mathematics, 100
Hulk, Robert Banner, superhuman strength, 90
He-Man, Prince Adam, superhuman strength, 92
Wolverine, Logan, retractable bone claws, 70"""

import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s),names=["Hero","Name","Special","Power"],skipinitialspace=True)
df.sort_values("Power",ascending=True, inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

#df.to_dict(orient="r")
#df.to_csv("output.csv",index=False)

output = '\n'.join([', '.join([str(i) for i in row]) for row in df.values])
print(output)
```